# Angular - Promises with Observable Test

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine, es6-promise

I'm coding a test in Angular.

The component that I want to test has this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cognitoService.isAuthenticated().then(() => this.loadForm(),
      () => this.router.navigate(['/home/login']));

  }

  loadForm() {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
    this.userProperties = new Map();
    this.cognitoService.getUserAttributes(['name', 'custom:lastName', 'email', 'picture', 'phone_number',
      'custom:id', 'custom:description']).subscribe(attributes => this.completeProfileForm(attributes));
  }
```

The **cognitoService.isAuthenticated()** method returns a Promise. And the **cognitoService.getUserAttributes** method returns an Observable.

The test is like this:

```
 it('should create', () => {

spyOn(cognitoService, 'getUserAttributes').and.callFake(function () {
  const userProperties = new Map();
  userProperties.set('custom:lastName', 'lastName');
  userProperties.set('name', 'firstName');
  userProperties.set('email', 'example@email.com');
  userProperties.set('picture', 'picture.png');
  userProperties.set('phone_number', '+5412123434');
  userProperties.set('custom:id', '1');
  userProperties.set('custom:description', 'description');
  return Observable.of(userProperties);
});

    spyOn(cognitoService, 'isAuthenticated').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
 expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

In that way, when I run the test, the terminal shows: Empty test suite
But if I change the code in this way:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.cognitoService.isAuthenticated().then(null,
      () => this.router.navigate(['/home/login']));
    this.loadForm();
  }
```

The test runs OK. But I don't like the code before, because I want to call the loadForm() method only when the promise is resolve.

Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Have you run `fixture.detectChanges()` before this function is called (inside a beforeEach() for example)?  If yes, then doing so will execute `ngOnInit()` before you are set up to test it (with your spy).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dmcgrandle ! fixture.detectChanges() will always call the ngOnInit() method?

Comment: Yes, fixture.detectChanges() exists so that a tester can delay the lifecycle hooks to set things up before invoking ngOnInit() for example.  See more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#componentfixture-methods)